# PHP - add to values of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I basically want to change the value of a multidimensional array by adding to the previous value.

Example:

```
$arr=array(1,2,3);

foreach($arr as $val){
    $arrTotal[1][2][3]=$val;
}
```

This would make $arrTotal[1][2][3]=3

What I really want is $arrTotal[1][2][3]=6

3+2+1.

I have tried an approach like so:

```
$arrTotal[1][2][3]+=$val;
```

But to no avail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easiest approach:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
$arrTotal[1][2][3] = array_sum($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

More general solution:

```
<?php

function hierarchical_array_sum(array $arr) {
    $parent = null;
    $current = $total = new ArrayObject;
    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        $parent = $current;
        $current = $current[$val] = new ArrayObject;
    }
    if ($parent !== null) {
        $parent[$val] = array_sum($arr);
    }
    $total = json_decode(json_encode($total), true);
}

var_dump(hierarchical_array_sum(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrTotal[1][2][3] = 0;
foreach($arr as $val){
    $arrTotal[1][2][3] = $arrTotal[1][2][3] + $val;
}
```

Comment: Not the easiest approach ;-)